# Set application as default in android

Tags: android, android-intent

How can i set my app as default. like i have make one application that contain the the QR code scanner functionality, I have used the ZXing library project for QR code scanner.
It is working file, but when i run the project I suffer from the "*complete action using*" option. When I click on my application scanner button it open the device camera but before that it ask for option. I want my application to be default for QR scanner. Means it won't appear *complete action using* option.

So how can I do this?

Comment: You want to only open the ZXing app, and not ask the user which app to open, if you click on your apps scanner button, do I understand that correctly?

Comment: @tknell - You are right. But ZXing is my library project it's not my original app, my original app is `ScanQR` and I want to open `ScanQR` app, not ask the user which app to open

Comment: Okay, and in your ScanQR app you have a scan button, which should open a scan activity`that is also in the ScanQR app? Or do you want to open the ScanQR app from another activity that is also from you?

Comment: @tknell - Right, I have scan button in `ScanQR` app. That open QR  scanner from the ZXing library that I have imported into `ScanQR`

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent filters in Manifest to specify actions your activity handles like below:

```
<activity class=".NoteEditor" android:label="@string/title_note">

         <intent-filter android:label="@string/resolve_edit">
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note" />
         </intent-filter>

         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note" />
         </intent-filter>

     </activity>
```

For instance action name for reading QR codes maybe `android.intent.readQR` you specify this action in intent filter, telling android that your app handles this action. When you do it right, your app should appear in that list.

Take a look at this link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Edit: Check this link for setting your app to default:

http://droidyue.com/blog/2014/01/12/set-the-preferred-application-in-android/

Comment: I don't want my application in the list, I want my application will be default one. means it set as default so there is no list is open to seletct the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you have included the ZXing app Project (https://github.com/zxing/zxing/tree/master/android), and not just the core, you can open the Activity that is responsible for the scanning directly, like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,CaptureActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Intents.Scan.ACTION); 
//or intent.setAction("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE","QR_CODE_MODE"): // for only scanning qr codes
startActivityForResult(intent, 9000); // replace 9000 with some request code you defined
```

and get the result in `onActivityResult` of your Activity:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(resultCode=9000){ // again, replace
            String result = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            ...
        }
    }
```